# How to create 2D or 3D cross sections from geological borehole data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, model, geology, cross-section

Is it possible to load borehole csv data that contains x, y, z coordinates into QGIS and create cross sections of the strata? It is data along a rail line so a DEM is not suitable. Just a 2D cross section would be fine.

I have looked through the similar question threads but the problem was never properly answered.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want more of a tutorial than a stack exchange-style answer to a specific question. A quick google of the phrase "cross-section of three-dimensional raster qgis" should lead you to a number of tutorials, such as these:

http://www.geokincern.com/?p=1452

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIR3z2jC4L4

Comment: Yes i came across that guide in my own google searches but felt it wasnt quite what i was after. I have borehole data not a surface map. Il see what i can get out of it though, it mentiones a section tool which could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to go outside of QGIS for this task you could give a piece of software called Groundhog Desktop a try. This is something I've been working on at the British Geological Survey which deals with borehole data and cross-section drawing. It's free to use and in Beta form at the moment.

[Groundhog Desktop](http://www.bgs.ac.uk/research/environmentalModelling/groundhogDesktop.html)